# How would you remotely detect interaction of a beam of 1 GeV protons with an aluminum sheet?

Tags: radiation, protons, particle-detectors, fluorescence

The inelastic interaction with an electron of the aluminum atom would knock them out of the atom, and would give rise to emission lines characteristic of aluminum when a free electron filled the vacant orbital.

There is also the interaction with the Al nucleus. What other radiation might be detected?

Comment: there are articles here with beam-material interactions https://e-publishing.cern.ch/index.php/CYR/issue/view/12

Comment: Spallated neutrons?

Comment: Excellent comments. Thanx to @JonCuster

Comment: Thanx @annav, excellent comment.